# Getting BSOD, is my RAM broken?

Tags: windows-7, windows, memory, bsod

I am getting BSOD maybe once every 2-3 weeks. I manage to take a picture of the latest:

[image]

Upon restart, I also get this error message from Windows:

> Problem signature:   Problem Event Name:  BlueScreen   OS
>   Version:  6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1   Locale ID:   1033
>
> Additional information about the problem:   BCCode:   1000007e
>   BCP1: FFFFFFFFC0000005   BCP2:    FFFFF880010921D1
>   BCP3: FFFFF88004119218   BCP4:    FFFFF88004118A70   OS Version:  6_1_7601
>   Service Pack: 1_0   Product:  256_1
>
> Files that help describe the problem:
>   C:\Windows\Minidump\012014-57626-01.dmp
>   C:\Windows\Temp\WER-58562-0.sysdata.xml
>
> Read our privacy statement online:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409
>
> If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our
>   privacy statement offline:   C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

What could be the issue?

Comment: Just a little remark: RAM is often guaranteed for life. I have never saw a problem with RAM banks for years, unless in extreme thermal conditions. Not to say those problems seen might have been caused by mortherboard northbridge chipset problems. I have no solution for your problem, but I would say the problem is most probably not in any RAM bank.

Comment: No your ram is not broken. It happens a lot of time with me but my PC is still working fine. It may be cause of over using the machine.

Comment: have you done a **chkdsk /r c:**?  Stop 7E is frequently the hard drive.

Comment: upload the dmp file from **C:\Windows\Minidump**

Comment: A handy guide to Bug Check codes by Microsoft is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Read it, they have specific instructions for your case. You suffered a memory access violation, which can be due to null-pointer exceptions in kernel space. In your case, it's highly probable that the driver `fltmgr.sys` caused it, you could confirm this by examining the dump and checking to which driver belongs the code loaded at address `FFFFF880010921D1` (the Bug Check Parameter 2). BCP3 and 4 can also explain more accurately what precisely happened.

Answer (score 0):

this tool may help you diagnose your problem better : [blue screen view](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html)

However from what I can see from a quick google search that this BSOD with that .sys file can be due to a ESET antivirus - using any antivirus on the machine? Otherwise that could also be due to a hardware issue with a drive, since [that .sys file is related to filesystem access](http://www.computerhope.com/cgi-bin/process.pl?p=fltmgr.sys)

Answer (score 0):

If it's not a hardware issue, it's probably a driver problem.

The given name of the driver `fltmgr.sys` may not be correct at this time, because the problem may occur later and then the wrong driver is specified as the culprit..

Activate driver verfier.
Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type `verifier` <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then `Create standard settings`. Next time you get a bluescreen, the driver name should be correct.

Your computer might be slower than normal, because additional checks are performed. To delete the driver verification, run `verifier` again and choose `Delete existing settings`.

Answer (score -1):

BSOD or Blue Screen of Death error does not occur due to hardware issues, it occurs due to virus/malware infection in windows. Follow below mentioned steps to fix this error:

•   Boot your system in safe mode with networking: for doing so, press F8 to enter into safe mode and then press down arrow to enter into safe mode with networking.

•   Make note of the file computer was unable to load in safe mode (when file loading was stopped and an error was returned).

•   When this is done, make a list of driver that needs to be upgraded. Take the help of file codes that you have noted down in prior step and perform a Google search for the same. Use another system.

•   Perform a complete system scan in safe mode itself. Use some strong antivirus/spyware/anti malware application like Immunet, Malwarebytes, kaspersky, Bitdefender, Avast, Avira etc.

•   After following above mentioned steps you can also perform a system restore after rebooting your system in safe mode with “Last Known Good Configuration”.

However, different BSOD error needs different solution. So be particular about the error while dealing with it. Hope this helps.

Comment: Not 100% of the time, in fact probably 85-90% of the time it is hardware or driver problems.

Comment: Your answer is incoherent, and I suspect you have no idea what you're talking about. Your answer says at the top that the problem is due to viruses or malware, but your troubleshooting steps recommend updating drivers. Which is the solution?